# Cannot modify association because the source reflection class is associated to via :has_many + rails 3.0.10

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Getting Following Error
**ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughCantAssociateThroughHasOneOrManyReflection in ProjectController#create**

Cannot modify association 'ProjectMaster#tag_masters' because the source reflection class 'TagMaster' is associated to 'ProjectTag' via :has_many.

Following are my models.

```
class ProjectTag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tag_masters
  has_many :project_masters
end

class TagMaster < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :project_tags
  has_many :project_masters, :through => :project_tags  
end

class ProjectMaster < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :project_tags
  has_many :tag_masters, :through => :project_tags
  # Some more code and associations here..
end
```

I am new to rails and tried to solve it but I don't think i can change my associations.

I am using rails 3.0.10

Please help me out here.

- Thanks

Comment: I think my associations were wrong. 

class ProjectTag < ActiveRecord::Base
 <br>  has_many :tag_masters 
 <br>  has_many :project_masters 
<br>end

instead of has_many; I had to use belongs_to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think my associations were wrong.

```
class ProjectTag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tag_masters 
  has_many :project_masters 
end
```

instead of `has_many`; I had to use `belongs_to`.