# Can't delete_all associated records with "has_many through"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I have 3 models:

**Shedule**

```
belongs_to :service
```

**Service**

```
belongs_to :user, :foreign_key => "owner"
has_many :shedules, :dependent => :destroy
```

**User**

```
has_many :services, :foreign_key => "owner", :dependent => :destroy
has_many :shedules, :through => :services, :foreign_key => "owner", :dependent => :destroy
```

Then i can see all shedules of user by `my_user.shedules`

My goal is deleting all shedules of user, then i try `my_user.shedules.delete_all` but get this error:

> ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughCantAssociateThroughHasOneOrManyReflection:
>   Cannot modify association 'User#shedules' because the source
>   reflection class 'Shedule' is associated to 'Service' via :has_many.

After some googling i find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8489325/cannot-modify-association-because-the-source-reflection-class-is-associated-to-v) and some other similar posts, but all of them dont fit to my problem.

Of course i can delete this by iterating the user services like

```
my_user.services.each do |s|
    s.shedules.delete_all
end
```

But i'm interesting why `my_user.shedules.delete_all` dont't work.

Thanks!

Comment: Try removing the foreign_key from this `has_many :shedules, :through => :services, :foreign_key => "owner", :dependent => :destroy`

Comment: Unfortunately, the same error

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1399394/dependent-destroy-on-a-has-many-through-association use `destroy` in order to trigger the callbacks of `:dependent => :destroy`

Comment: I want to delete only shedules, but not service which they belong to.

Answer (score 4):

Found an easier solution than presented here before.

```
Schedule.merge(my_user.schedules).delete_all
```

I prefer this because it is only one database query and I do not have to remember what the foreign key is named.

It works because:

`Schedule.merge(my_user.schedules).to_sql == my_user.schedules.to_sql`

Answer (score 1):

Try:-

```
my_user.shedules.destroy_all
```

OR

```
Shedule.delete_all(:owner => my_user.id)
```

Comment: This ans is working for me. You are not able to delete shedules MAy be because your shedules are also associated with services.

Comment: Your table 'Shedule' is associated to 'Service' as well as with 'User' hence you are not able to delete the shedules using delete_all or destroy_all.

Comment: I don't understand why. Shedule belongs to Service and Service belongs to User. This means that table Shedules has field service_id. So why can't i delete all shedules if nothing depends of it?

Comment: In terms of SQL i want:
DELETE FROM shedules
WHERE service_id in 
(SELECT id FROM services WHERE owner = ?). I dont see why it cant delete shedules.

Comment: Try this:- Shedule.delete_all(:user_id => my_user.id)

Comment: Ooops! Use owner instead of user_id as your foreign_key is "owner".

Comment: THere is no field 'owner' in table 'Shedule'. Link is: Shedule.service_id -> Service.owner -> User.id.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can delete the `schedules` using the association. You can delete these records by simply finding them yourself.

```
Shedule.where(service_id: user.services.pluck(&:id)).delete_all
user.reload # optional
```

If you use this often you can define a method on `User`

```
def delete_schedules
  Shedule.where(service_id: user.services.pluck(&:id)).delete_all
end
```